# Adjusting the Menu Folder Margin

Tags: css

I have a folder that drops down when you hover over it, however I've placed a 20px margin-top to the drop down so it's not pushed up against the main navigation.  I like the spacing however when you move your mouse to go select a sub-item the menu disappears.

How would you adjust the margin of the drop down so that it stays so the user can select an item in it?

```
> ul {
        display: none;
      }


      &:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
        text-align: left;
        z-index:1000;
        background-color:@nav-folder-bg-color;
        width:150px;
        padding: 10px;
        list-style: none;
        border-radius:@nav-border-radius;
        margin-top:20px;

        > li a {
            color:black;
            font-size: .8em;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

      }
```

EDIT: Here is the menu I am working on - http://menudemo.squarespace.com/home

Answer (score 0):

Put the margin on the first LI in the sub-menu:

```
&:hover > ul li:first-child {
   margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: I tried added it and it didn't add the spacing that I wanted.. Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add

```
  height:50px;
```

to .main-navigation ul li